# Excel Formula to highlight cell based on time difference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to highlight a cell if that cell and another cell its within 1.5 hours.  So if A1 is `5/9/2016 06:55` and A4 is `5/9/2016 08:10`, they are within 1.5 hours apart, so highlight A4.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187235/excel-programm-cells-to-change-colour-based-on-another-cell) and [this Office page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-e1c78778-749b-49a3-b13e-737715505ff6), you want to set a formula like:

1. Select cell A4 and click the Conditional Formatting button in the ribbon and choose "New Rule"
2. Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
3. Enter the formula `=IF(ABS(A4-A1)*24 < 1.5, TRUE, FALSE)`
4. If you want cell A1 to be a fixed reference so that copy-paste will work, you can instead enter the formula `=IF(ABS(A4-$A$1)*24 < 1.5, TRUE, FALSE)`, or [name the cell](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64)
5. Set the format to highlight the cell

Comment: Thanks, it work, but its not letting me copy it down like a shortcut to do it with other cells.

Comment: OK, see the new step 4 to see how to get copy-paste to work.

Comment: I want to do it like A2 with A1 then A3 with A2, so and so.

Comment: Isn't that just `=IF(ABS(A2-A1)*24 < 1.5, TRUE, FALSE)`, then copy-paste? It works for me with Excel 2010...