# Excel formula formatting

Tags: excel

is it possible to use a formula in conditional formatting to change the fill color of one cell based on the fill color of another cell. All I can find is value based formatting. I have a large sheet that has many rows in one color with nothing in the cell and I want to change those cells to another color without having to select them.

[image: Example sheet]

Comment: Why not apply a conditional format of `no fill` if cells are empty?

Comment: You can even search for a color and replace it with another one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187235/excel-programm-cells-to-change-colour-based-on-another-cell

Comment: Mr Excel has a UDF for testing for cell formatting.  https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/663739-vba-udf-test-if-cell-colored.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Excel 4.0 Macro Function` `GET.CELL`:

> Returns information about the formatting, location, or contents of a
>   cell. Use GET.CELL in a macro whose behavior is determined by the
>   status of a particular cell.
>
> **Syntax
>
>   GET.CELL**(**type_num**, reference)
>
> **type_num** = 39:
>   Shade background color as a number in the range 1 to 56. If color is automatic, returns 0.

With cell `B1` selected create a named range called `FillColour`.
This refers to:  `=GET.CELL(38,A1)`

Now, if you enter the formula `=FillColour` in cell B1 it will show a different value when you change the background colour of cell A1.
**NB:**  You may have to manually force a recalculation for it to work.

Next add conditional formatting rules:  `=FillColour=29` will be TRUE if the cell to the left of the *CF* is formatted as purple (RGB: 177, 160, 199).